# Programmatically retrieve Microsoft Office 365 account

Tags: ms-office, keychain, office-365

I'm trying to programmatically retrieve the Office 365 account in use by users on a Mac fleet.

I discovered this is apparently stored in the keychain, either in the `msoCredentialSchemeADAL` internet password or in the `OneAuthAccount` generic password  (both in *Where* field). The first is sometimes missing, but the latter seems always to be present.

Now I found some computers where the `msoCredentialSchemeADAL` ID is not matching the Office logged in user. And I have two `OneAuthAccount` entries, one with the same ID, and the other one with the ID matching the user showing up in (e.g.) Word.

What's the correct way to obtain the Office365 User UUID? I was unable to sort it out, so far my searches were unsuccessful.